# Variadic template declaration from single integer argument?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, variadic

Is it possible to statically declare *N* same-type template arguments from single integer type template argument? Potentially something similar to this:

```
template < int N >
class MyTemplatedType {
    // base type, known
    typedef float base_t;
    // instance of some other templated class with *N* template arguments
    SomeOtherClass< base_t, base_t, base_t, base_t, ..., base_t > foo;
    /* ... */
}
```

I understand I can use a variadic template and use it directly to the member instance declaration, but I was wondering if there would be some kind of SFINAE implementation that would resolve a single integer template parameter, as the syntax would be much cleaner and intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a meta-function that accepts `N`, `base_t`, and `SomeOtherClass`, and recursively calls itself with a smaller `N`, each time tacking on `base_t` to the end of a growing parameter pack:

```
template <int N, typename T, template<typename...> typename C, typename ...Ts>
struct expand { 
    using type = typename expand<N-1, T, C, T, Ts...>::type;
};
```

For the base case, when `N` goes down to 0, the meta-function yields `SomeOtherClass` instantiated with the parameter pack of `N` `base_t` types:

```
template <typename T, template<typename...> typename C, typename ...Ts>
struct expand<0, T, C, Ts...> { 
    using type = C<Ts...>;
};
```

Also, convenience alias is nice to avoid having to say `typename` at the call site:

```
template <int N, typename T, template<typename...> typename C>
using expand_t = typename expand<N, T, C>::type;
```

---

Now at the call site you can write:

```
expand_t<N, base_t, SomeOtherClass> foo; 
// equivalent to 
// SomeOtherClass< base_t, base_t, ..., base_t > foo;
//               ^^^        N times          ^^^
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h3vW98).

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Some observations though 1) I get that the parameter pack `...Ts` encodes the recursively growing list of template arguments, but why exactly do we need the to pass a second `T` argument on the recursive call, 2) what would change if one were to attempt to use the parameter pack as function argument, instead of template argument e.g. `void myFunction(const float& args...)`?

Comment: 1) That's how the new `Ts...` is created in the recursive call: from `T, Ts...`. 2) I'm not sure what you mean by "instead of template argument". The declaration you've shown isn't valid C++ at least.

Comment: Ah ok it makes sense now. As for 2) what I meant was how would I unpack the parameter pack when declaring a function that takes `N` arguments of type `T`?

Comment: I think you're asking about "pack expansion". Search for that term, and see if that addresses your question.

Comment: I'm marginally familiar with parameter pack expansion, my point was just how to tweak your solution to encode just the variable length parameter and not the template specialization of a class `C`, so that I could declare a function `void someFunction(expand<5, base_t>... args)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, using tuples and helper templates to assemble the desired class. A little additional sugar can make the resulting syntax "cleaner" Tested with gcc 10.2:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// Create std::tuple<T ...>, with T repeated N times.

template<int N, typename T>
struct tuple_list : tuple_list<N-1, T> {

    typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename tuple_list<N-1, T>
                    ::tuple_t>(),
                    std::declval<std::tuple<T> &&>())
             ) tuple_t;
};

template<typename T>
struct tuple_list<0, T> {

    typedef std::tuple<> tuple_t;
};

template<typename ...> struct SomeOtherClass {};

// And now, replace `std::tuple` with SomeOtherClass 

template<typename tuple_t> struct make_some_other_class;

template<typename ...Args>
struct make_some_other_class<std::tuple<Args...>> {

    typedef SomeOtherClass<Args...> type_t;
};

template < int N >
class MyTemplatedType {

    typedef float base_t;

public:

    // The payload is not exactly "clean", but one more helper
    // template can make the syntax here a little bit nicer...

    typename make_some_other_class< typename tuple_list<N, base_t>
                    ::tuple_t >::type_t foo;
};

void foobar(MyTemplatedType<3> &bar)
{
    SomeOtherClass<float, float, float> &this_works=bar.foo;
}
```